# What makes WCF ServiceHost crash?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, servicehost

I have a Windows Service that exposes the same interface on 4 ports using WCF. The addresses are:

```
net.tcp://localhost:1200/IContract
net.tcp://localhost:1201/IContract
net.tcp://localhost:1202/IContract
net.tcp://localhost:1203/IContract
```

This service is in production for a long time and there are times it breaks and I cannot even telnet the port with the problem. I usually have to reset the service.

I really don't get the point of having lots of ports for the same contract, but this solution probably masked the original problem.

Anyway, what could be making the servicehost to crash on the server side? Could a client crash the servicehost, or it may be related to some kind of denial of service?

PS: this problem occurs esporadically and I'm not able to reproduce in dev. Using a trace in production is not practical too.

Thanks

Comment: Have you added logging to monitor what's happening inside the service as it runs? Do several clients hit the service at the same time? How's it configured? Unhandled exceptions could cause the service to stop responding see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136048/unhandled-exception-will-make-wcf-service-crash for more info.

Comment: Yes, there are several clients connected on the same port getting lots of data. The program is not protected for a DOS attack, but if is this the case, should this behaviour be expected? Maybe it is easier to just reopen the channel whenever it drops...

Answer (score 2):

You can ask [Dr. Watson](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308538) for help. You can configure [WEH](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/winlogo/maintain/StartWER.mspx) for your application (provided you can sign your code). Or you can collect crash information using tools like [bugcollect.com](http://bugcollect.com/), [exceptioneer.com](http://exceptioneer.com/public/WhatIsExceptioneer.aspx) or [errortc.com](http://errortc.com/).

But ultimately, you can't just simply ask 'how can a arbitrary process crash'. There are simply too many ways. You can get at best a generic answer ('It crashed because it dereferenced a protected address').

Answer (score 1):

Service hosts can fail. It doesn't matter if you fix this or not, they are just goign to fail in a different fashion next time.

I account for this by creating my own subtype of ServiceHost that includes logging and automatic restarting capabilities.

```
Public Class RestartableServiceHost
    Inherits ServiceHost

    Private m_Log As FileLogger
    Private ReadOnly m_FaultResponse As ServiceHostFaultResponse
    Private ReadOnly m_Name As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal serviceType As Type, ByVal faultResponse As ServiceHostFaultResponse, ByVal log As FileLogger)
        MyBase.New(serviceType)
        If serviceType Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("serviceType", "serviceType is nothing.")
        If log Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("log", "log is nothing.")


        m_Log = log
        m_FaultResponse = faultResponse
        m_Name = serviceType.Name & " service host"
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal singletonInstance As Object, ByVal faultResponse As ServiceHostFaultResponse, ByVal log As FileLogger)
        MyBase.New(singletonInstance)

        If singletonInstance Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("singletonInstance", "singletonInstance is nothing.")
        If log Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("log", "log is nothing.")

        m_Log = log
        m_FaultResponse = faultResponse
        m_Name = singletonInstance.GetType.Name & " service host"
    End Sub

    Private Sub AamServiceHost_Closed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Closed
        m_Log.Write(m_Name & " has closed")
    End Sub

    Private Sub AamServiceHost_Closing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
        m_Log.Write(m_Name & " is closing")
    End Sub

    Private Sub AamServiceHost_Faulted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Faulted
        m_Log.Write(m_Name & " has faulted.")

        Select Case m_FaultResponse
            Case ServiceHostFaultResponse.None
                'NOP
            Case ServiceHostFaultResponse.AbortReopenThrow
                Try
                    Abort()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    m_Log.Write("Unable to abort SecurityMasterChangeListener Service Host", ex, Severity.Warning)
                End Try
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
                Try
                    Open()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    m_Log.Write("Unable to reopen SecurityMasterChangeListener Service Host.", ex, Severity.ErrorServiceFailed)
                    Throw
                End Try
        End Select

    End Sub

    Private Sub AamServiceHost_Opened(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Opened
        m_Log.Write(m_Name & " has opened")
    End Sub

    Private Sub AamServiceHost_Opening(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Opening
        m_Log.Write(m_Name & " is opening")
    End Sub

    Private Sub AamServiceHost_UnknownMessageReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As UnknownMessageReceivedEventArgs) Handles Me.UnknownMessageReceived
        m_Log.Write("SecurityMasterChangeListener Service Host has received an unknown message. The message will be ignored.", Severity.ErrorTaskFailed)
    End Sub

End Class
```