# Can a WCF standalone process unexpectedly die?

Tags: wcf, crash

I want to be certain that a WCF service running as a standalone executable (or windows service) cannot crash.

In case it wasn't obvious, I'm looking for more than a yes or no answer.

Comment: look this http://stackoverflow.com/q/1136048/1477076

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It can run out of disk space or memory space. Or some application with protected access can come along and corrupt it's memory. The CPU could experience an intermittent hardware failure that results in some otherwise impossible set of variable values that lead to a crash. They'res a myriad of possible though unlikely scienarious that could cause it to crash unexpectedly.

Comment: And now the killer question. Does it make sense to restart the process if it dies for one of these reasons?

Comment: @kelloti How are the current transactions being handled in the event of a crash?

Comment: We're using MongoDB, so no database transactions (aside from the usual fire-n-forget philosophy)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, these usually die because of bugs in the code or lack of exception handling around accessing resources external to the running process.  I.E. Files, Database, Web-services, etc.

Spencer's assessment accounts things you cannot control.

Comment: No - bugs are caught by WCF. They don't cause the process to die.